# What is a good alternative to spinrite for OS X?

Tags: osx, hard-disk, repair

Currently, [SpinRite](https://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm) does not support OS X...or only supports it through a VM which means much of it's functionality will not work. In short, *SpinRite* offers repair and recovery and preventative maintenance (details/technical background below).

Are there any OS X tools that offer the same feature set?

SpinRite is $89. I would be looking in that general price range, but would consider something far more expensive if it worked as well as spinrite does.

---

The features I am looking for are taken from [this video](https://www.grc.com/sr/whatitdoes.htm) explaining what it does:

Steve Gibson explains that hard drives degrade over time because manufacturers are unable to provide us with perfect media as our densities have increased. Since drives can handle bad sectors, spinrite assists the drive in locating the bad sectors by reading the entire drive and writing all of the data back to the drive. For when the drive refuses to read a sector, it tries and tries again to get the drive to read the sector using different methods like starting from different positions on the disk and reading at different velocities. Additionally, it has some statistical methods for reconstructing lost data.

Comment: There's a free tool that ships with OSX called fsck. I'm not sure if it does all the things spinrate does but it certainly can detect bad sectors and can attempt to repair them

Comment: Spinrite 6.1 with native MacOS support is soon to come. Steve from GRC just announced he is working on it now.